# Receiving socket error while connecting to cloud SQL

Tags: android, sockets, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect to cloud SQL using android studio. Receiving this error

```
07-30 16:51:12.511 23120-23120/com.example.pratyush.geofencing W/System.err: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/cloud/sql/mysql/SslSocketFactory;
```

My Code:

```
public void getDatafromSQL() {
    Log.d("GeoL", "getSQL");
    Connection connection;
    String query = "Some query";
    try {
        String databaseName = "dbName";

        String instanceConnectionName = "instnce name";

        String jdbcUrl = String.format(
                "jdbc:mysql://google/%s?cloudSqlInstance=%s&"
                        + "socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory",
                databaseName,
                instanceConnectionName);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, "user", "pwd");

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
        Log.d("GeoL", String.valueOf(resultSet));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am using mysql connector jar and mysql socket factory jar as dependencies.

Also I am unable to use compile 'com.google.cloud.sql:mysql-socket-factory:1.0.3' this as a dependency.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library contains multiple jars. If you are manually adding the jars, you need to also add its dependencies (e.g. jdbc-socket-factory-core jar, maybe others).

Having said that, you really ought to not be manually packaging jars because it's a tedious and error prone process.

Lastly, unless this is a toy app for yourself you should not connect directly to the database from your mobile app. You're essentially giving out direct access to your database to anyone that has a copy of the app.